# Specifying the custom account for transaction execution in truffle

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am wandering how to set the custom account to execute transaction? For example in truffle console i have something like

> Hello.deployed().then(function(){h = instance})

, and then

> h.exetuceTransaction()

will burn gas from the accounts[0] by default. How can I specify the account from which I want to send this transaction (for example accouts[1])?

Comment: We just have to specify the fromparameter when calling executeTransaction({"from" : "0x..." })

Comment: I copy pasted the answer I gave you in a comment last time ;)
And next time ask your questions on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to specify the `from` parameter when calling `executeTransaction({"from" : "0x..." })` check [The doc](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction)